# "intellij idea" debug static class

Tags: java, android, debugging, intellij-idea, static-members

I have the following code in my android project I develop using "intellij idea":

```
Settings.Secure.putInt(this.getContentResolver(),Settings.Secure.ADB_ENABLED, 1);
```

I have break point next to this line, and when I stop here unfortunately I can not see Static fields of Settings class. I have tried:

```
Class g1 = Settings.class;
```

But can not see internals of that class anyway.

What to change in "intellij idea" settings to see those Static fields.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you hit a breakpoint, in the `Debugger` tab of your debug instance, right-click on any variable, then choose `Customize Data Views` and make sure `Static field` (and `Static final fields`, depending on your needs) are checked.

See https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/customize-data-views.html for more info.